# "James will [...] implore the big man to *make* every part of his 7-foot-1, 275-pound frame *felt* by the opposition."

Tags: grammar

> But the lighthearted interplay often devolves during games. [LeBron] James will
>   shout at Mozgov for a failed defensive assignment, criticize him when
>   a play isn’t executed properly, implore the big man to **make** every part
>   of his 7-foot-1, 275-pound frame **felt** by the opposition.

I want to know if this sentence uses proper grammar. I've checked the grammar of "make" in a combination of the subject+verb and subject+past participle. But, according to my dictionary, we can use only "understood" and "heard" as the past participle in that grammatical construction.

So, can we use *felt*? And does the sentence mean "LeBron want him to overawe opposition player?"

---

*Additional information that is not part of the question:*

Nice to meet you. It's my first post on this website. I'm Japanese and and a beginner at English.

Comment: I doubt that you've quoted it correctly, even though it appears to be a "headline", where the rules of construction are somewhat different.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because appears to be incorrectly quoted (there are two different versions in title and question), plus no context is supplied.

Comment: Thank you for your replying.That is not headline, part of article.

Comment: Then quote several **complete** lines from the article.

Comment: But the lighthearted interplay often devolves during games. James will shout at Mozgov for a failed defensive assignment, criticize him when a play isn’t executed properly, implore the big man to make every part of his 7-foot-1, 275-pound frame felt by the opposition.

Comment: Above sentence is context.

Comment: Those sentences (which I've edited into your question) are much different from what you previously quoted.  Why did you even bother with the other stuff??

Comment: I can't get your point?

Comment: Why did you initially misquote the article?  How are we supposed to interpret it if it's so badly misquoted?

Comment: Thank you for your aplying.I can understand it.Thank you very much.And I'll watch out my mistake:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> James will shout at Mozgov for a failed defensive assignment,
>
> criticize him when a play isn’t executed properly,
>
> implore the big man to make every part of his 7-foot-1, 275-pound
>   frame felt by the opposition.

There are three things that "James will" do: shout, criticize, and implore.

What he (James) implores is for "the big man" (Mozgov) to make himself "felt" -- to use his height and strength to overwhelm and intimidate the opposition.

Comment: It can be so unfair when you go to the effort of composing an answer, only to find that a substantial edit to the question - worthy as the edit might be - renders your answer somewhat oblique to the question as it now appears.  But at least you got the early tick of approval :-)

Comment: @Chappo - Actually, I did the initial edit, to put the actual text into the question.  Sumelic merely rearranged things a bit and cleaned up some of the OP's wording.

Answer (score 1):

Sumelic's edits have made this question suitable to post an answer. To summarise, the question asks if "make+object" can take other past participles like "felt", or it it restricted to just "heard" and "understood".

You can add *any* past participle after "make+object" if the past participle can be sensibly used to modify the object. "His 7-foot-1, 275 pound frame" is the object here. To simplify, let's replace that with the pronoun "it".

**"Make it felt"** is standard English. So are:

- make it known
- make it seen
- make it shortened
- make it eliminated
- make it terraformed

and so on.